# Prevent lock screen from locking the computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, screensaver

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise (1607) system that we use for Kiosk. My goal is to prevent this computer from going to the login screen after it leaves the screensaver. Currently, I believe all of my settings are correct, though it's still going to the logon screen after we leave the screen saver.

- We're on a domain, so I've set GPO to go to the screen saver after a minute, but not go to the logon screen.
- I've confirmed that no other policies are being configured on the machine (through gpresult and rsop.msc)
- I've attempted to remove the registry for locking the screen
- Power savings are all correct. I have it set to not go to sleep or turn off the screen.
- This happens on multiple domain profiles.
- I've tried disjoining and rejoining the domain.
- The "Screen Saver Settings" page shows the wait timeout at 1 minute and "On resume, display logon screen" is unchecked.

I'm kind of at a loss because this system is several hours away and rebuilding isn't an option given it's a vendor supplied computer.

Comment: home vs pro there are going to be differences, i dont have a domain to do a proof for you, but registry changes do require a reboot

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-lock-screen

https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Disable-the-Lock-Screen-in-Windows-10 .  <--most recent

Comment: It's Enterprise and I have rebooted multiple times. The policy is in place and greying out the relevant options, showing the 1 minute timeout and the box unchecked for "On resume, display logon screen".